How can I use absolute path with org-download?
I do have an absolute path as my org-download directory, but whenever I org-download an image, the link that is created uses a relative path in the buffer.
#+DOWNLOADED: screenshot @ 2024-05-24 14:21:36
[[file:../../pic/raster/org-download/20240524-142136_screenshot.png]]

How come?
I have defined:
org-download-image-dir is a variable defined in ‘org-download.el’.

Its value is "~/ds/pic/raster/org-download"
Original value was nil

org-link-file-path-type is a variable defined in ‘ol.el’.

Its value is ‘absolute’
Original value was ‘adaptive’


This means that when I try to copy the link to another buffer, the image link breaks.

What do you mean by "uses a relative path in the buffer"?

Check the value of org-link-file-path-type. Its doc string says:
How the path name in file links should be stored.
Valid values are:

relative  Relative to the current directory, i.e. the directory of the file
          into which the link is being inserted.
absolute  Absolute path, if possible with ~ for home directory.
noabbrev  Absolute path, no abbreviation of home directory.
adaptive  Use relative path for files in the current directory and sub-
          directories of it.  For other files, use an absolute path.

Alternatively, users may supply a custom function that takes the
full filename as an argument and returns the path.


You probably have set it to relative. Setting it to absolute should work well for your case.

This is why I think twice before answering any question of yours: you don't provide any feedback. No acceptance, no up-voting, not even a comment. I'll even take down-voting at this point as long as it is justified: any response is better than the deafening silence of your non-responses.

I'll get to all answers, eventually, but there are just too many balls in the air;). This answer is correct for the given question, so I'l mark it as solved. Thank you, again.
